# Duplicate condition in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want to know how SQL Server executes this query:

```
Select * 
from sampletable 
where id = 2 
  and name = 'xyz' 
  and id = 2;
```

You can see that `id = 2` appears twice in the above query. Will SQL Server ignore duplicate conditions, or will it be executed twice?

Will having duplicate condition check impact performance in any way?

Comment: Queries should be made with a lot of caution. And not automatically put together. So if there are duplicates in your query you are doing something very wrong.

Comment: The answer is that it probably depends...but if you can see that your `WHERE` clause has redundancies, then why not fix them?

Comment: This is just a sample query, in my project we dynamically generating filters (based on different components), where i could see duplicate conditions. I just wanted to know will it impact performance or will it cause issues in any kind.

Comment: See the execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a problem for the SQL engine because the SQL statement parser will just ignore the second occurrence.

Regarding performance, there won't be any significant impact also as the SQL statement parsing phase is only a fraction of time compared to the actual data retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

For what i see the query will ignore the name if the id is equals to 2 since the column id is put on 2 different cases